# Searching through worksheets and paste on a sheet the results if found

Tags: vba, excel

[Desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lgxO.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkFWP.png)So Basically what i have here calculates a the range of temperatures then searches through all the sheets for those ranges copies and pastes them on a selected sheet. what i am having difficulty is having to seperate the results from each sheet as the come back clustered.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tempint As Integer
Dim tempend As Integer
Dim tempstep As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim nt As Integer
Dim xtemp As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer


tempint = ComboBox_TempInt.Value
tempend = ComboBox_TempEnd.Value
tempstep = ComboBox_TempStep.Value


Userform1.Range("A2:c1000").ClearContents' to clear sheet where  results are pasted 

For Each ws In Sheets
     ws.Select

       nt = (tempend - tempint) / tempstep 'to get number of results 
         For k = 1 To (nt + 1)
          xtemp = tempint + (k - 1) * tempstep


    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 2 To finalrow
     If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = xtemp Then
     Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
     Userform1.Select

      Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
  xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
     ws.Select
     End If
    Next i
   Next k

 Next ws
```

[image]

The results just come back on each other would like the sheet name to separate each result

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO! Your question title should be something you'd type into Google when searching for a solution to that specific problem, so that your question can be useful for other people. Cheers!

Comment: use ws.Name to return the name ?

Comment: Could you cut down the size of your pic and add an illustration of your desired results?

Comment: Sorry about that, its my first time here on SO @MathieuGuindon noted.

Comment: @SJR would do that now

Comment: Am having difficulty uploading a picture of the desired results but a link was added to the Question

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I removed the Select but otherwise have only added a line for the worksheet name. Shouldn't you clear more columns than A-C at the start though? A more efficient approach would be AutoFilter or Find which would avoid looping through every row.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tempint As Long
Dim tempend As Long
Dim tempstep As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim nt As Long
Dim xtemp As Long
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Long

tempint = ComboBox_TempInt.Value
tempend = ComboBox_TempEnd.Value
tempstep = ComboBox_TempStep.Value

Userform1.Range("A2:c1000").ClearContents ' to clear sheet where  results are pasted

For Each ws In Sheets
    With ws
        userform1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Name
        nt = (tempend - tempint) / tempstep 'to get number of results
        For k = 1 To (nt + 1)
            xtemp = tempint + (k - 1) * tempstep
            finalrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To finalrow
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = xtemp Then
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 8)).Copy
                    Userform1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                End If
            Next i
        Next k
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your swift response. I have added extra columns to be cleared and also do as you suggested above but I am not getting any results displayed on the Userform1 sheet.

Comment: I've made a small change above but not sure it will make a big difference. Try stepping through the code to see what's happening. As far as I can see I haven't changed anything which would affect the comparison with xtemp.

Comment: I have done the stepping through and I think the problem am having now is between the I loop as the search values are not being pasted but the sheet names are appearing as expected.

Comment: Does the code actually get to the copy line at all? I take it Userform1 is a sheet code name? It should be excluded from the ws loop.

Comment: Can you try replacing my line `Userform1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` with yours `Userform1.Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` just in case there are values buried a long way down the sheet. And before you run the code manually clear all the cells on Userform1 in case there is anything below row 2000.

Comment: Thanks I have tried doing that. Yes the worksheet Userform1 is where all results are displayed and is usually empty initially. I tried taking it out of the loop but didn't work out. Stepping through I also noticed that the code is presently only searching through the userform1 for the xtemp .

Comment: Are all the sheets in the same file, the one containing the macro? can you put a breakpoint on the Copy line and see if it ever gets there?

Comment: Thank you very much for the support  @SJR.

Answer (score 0):

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQAk2.jpg)

This is the code i would have to settle for.

```
Private Sub Cmd_Button_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tempint As Long
Dim tempend As Long
Dim tempstep As Long
Dim k As Integer
Dim nt As Integer
Dim xtemp As Long
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer


  tempint = ComboBox_TempInt.Value
  tempend = ComboBox_TempEnd.Value
   tempstep = ComboBox_TempStep.Value


   Userform1.Range("A2:H1000").ClearContents

      For Each ws In Sheets
       ws.Select
    Userform1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = ws.Name
  nt = (tempend - tempint) / tempstep
   For k = 1 To (nt + 1)
    xtemp = tempint + (k - 1) * tempstep


finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To finalrow
     If Cells(i, 1).Value = xtemp Then

     Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy

     Userform1.Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

     End If
   Next i
Next k


 Next ws
 Unload UserForm_propeties
 Userform1.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: There's absolutely no need to Select the worksheet. When you used my code, did you put it in the button click event as I did not do that - that was missing from your original code?

Comment: Yes I did put it in the button click